# How to print correctly an N-ary tree with dfs pre-order

Tags: java, tree

I did a recursive pre-order depth-first search function of an N-ary tree in order to traverse it and print,but I want to remove the last space in the print. How can I do that without define other functions?

```
 public void printdfs() {

    int sz = this.children.size();
    if (sz > 0) {
        System.out.print(getValue() + " ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(" " + getValue());
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        MyTree object = this.children.get(i);
        System.out.print(".");
        object.printdfs();
    }

}

Output: 8 .20 .25 . 95. 70. 80. 30. 40. 10. 9
```

My structure of the N-ary tree is:

```
public class MyTree {
private int data;
private LinkedList<MyTree> children;

public MyTree(int data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.children = new LinkedList<>();
}
public int getValue() {
    return this.data;
}
public void addChild(MyTree child) {
    this.children.addFirst(child);
}
}
```

Comment: Of course there will be an extra space before the first number when you do `" " + getValue()`.  When `sz > 0`, it means there are children to print, so add the space after `getValue()`.  Otherwise there are no children, so don't add the space.

Comment: @geneSummons now there are 8 20 25  95 70 80 30 40 10 9 two spaces between 25 and 95.

Comment: Where does that second blank space come from?  As long as you are only ever adding one space after `getValue()` and not before, I don't know how two spaces can appear between two numbers in your list. (unless you somehow have a MyTree object with `data = null;` somewhere in the collection.)  If you add, for testing, `System.out.print(".");` right before the for loop, how does the "." affect your result? (The dot represents each "level" of recursion)

Comment: I edited the code with the output @geneSummons

Comment: it's normal I think it prints like this way because it starts with " " + value plus there is value + " " before.. so space + space = double space :/

Comment: Done by myself :D

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < childrens.size(); i++) {
       MyTree object = childrens.get(i);
       if (i == (childrens.size() - 1)) {
          object.printdfs().trim();
       }
       else {
          object.printdfs();
       }
    }
```

EDIT after comments: Would something like this work?

```
public void printdfs(PrintStream ps) {
    ps.print(getValue() + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < childrens.size(); i++) {
       MyTree object = childrens.get(i);
       object.printdfs(ps);
    }
}
```

Then you have a reference to the Stream object you originally pass in to the `printdfs()` method and you can then print out a substring of the Stream's data after `printdfs()` returns.

Or maybe you just want something like this?

```
public void printdfs() {
    int sz = childrens.size();
    if (sz < 0) {
        System.out.print(getValue() + " ");
    }
    else {
        System.out.print(getValue());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
       MyTree object = childrens.get(i);
       object.printdfs();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the trim method,it is not defined. I tryed a lot of things in my code but I don't know to fix my problem of the print. @geneSummons

Comment: if `object.printdfs()` has a void return type, it prints directly to the System.out stream, and you can't change the code, I don't think there is anything you can do about the trailing blank space.  But if you can make the method return a String or take a Stream input, then you can `trim()` the "final" output before displaying on screen.

Comment: I can change the code but I can't implement other functions

Comment: Like the second function,you can use only that but the output is 820259570803040109 and I want like that: 8 20 25 95 70 80 30 40 10 9 without the hidden space at the end

Comment: edited @geneSummons but now there is the space at start! :|